# I saw this on a malicious website. What is this html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: snippet of html]

What are these fields "lf-redirect-offer", "lf-untouched", "lf-pristine"? I know normal html tags can have normal fields like class, id, name, value; but what are these other names/fields? Are these javascript files inside of html elements? How would you normally use "FOO" inside of an html tag like

> ```
>    <input type='text' class='cool' FOO>
> ```

I'm more interested in what those fields are in html/css/javascript terms than that fact it could be malicious in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're nothing more than empty HTML attributes. HTML elements can be given (almost any) attribute string:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(
  div.hasAttribute('lf-untouched'),
  div.hasAttribute('somethingThatDoesntExist'),
);
```

```html
<div lf-redirect-offer lf-untouched lf-pristine></div>
```

You can add/remove such things with `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.hasAttribute('attrib1'));
div.removeAttribute('attrib1');
console.log(div.hasAttribute('attrib1'));

div.setAttribute('attrib2', '');
console.log(div.hasAttribute('attrib2'));
```

```html
<div attrib1></div>
```

HTML elements having arbitrary attributes like these aren't malicious at all. (That said, it's a better idea to set data attributes instead, which are exactly the same, except that they start with `data-`.)

Comment: Big difference with data-attributes is that the latter do map to the IDL `dataset`, and that the former are actually invalid (well only validators would care but still...)